# How to skip the first n item(s) of an iterator in Rust?

Tags: iterator, rust

When iterating over arguments (for example) thats the most straightforward way to skip the first *N* elements?

eg:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    for arg in env::args() {
        println!("Argument: {}", arg);
    }
}
```

I tried `env::args()[1..]` but slicing isn't supported.

Whats the simplest way to skip the first arguments of an iterator?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Turns out the [`.skip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) method can be used, eg:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    for arg in env::args().skip(1) {
        println!("Argument: {}", arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do something like

```
  fn main() {
      let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
      for x in &args[1..]
      {
          println!("{:?}", x);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation of this solution (and how it compares to other answers)?

Comment: The question posted is very specific to iterators and how to skip n elements while using an iterator. This answer collects the iterator into a collection and then slices into it, solves the problem, but not specifically with iterators i.e. without collecting. The top answer is correct and should have been the accepted answer.